# Null pointer exception on view obtained inside fragment's onViewCreated method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm not entirely sure what other kind of information/code I should provide. The strange thing is in a different fragment and activity this almost identical code is working. Here is my `onViewCreated` method:

**Inside Fragment:**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mHelveticaTF = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Helvetica.otf");
    oopsTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noClub_oops); // I've tried getView() and getActivity() - same result
    oopsTV.setTypeface(mHelveticaTF); // Null pointer exception here.
}
@Override
public void View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_no_club_membership, container, false);
}
```

The null pointer exception occurs at the call to `setTypeface` on oopsTV (which is apparently null). `onCreateView` seems to be inflating the correct .xml file. `R.id.noClub_oops` definitely is in my .xml file as a TextView.

This null pointer exception also occurs in onCreateView after the fragment is inflated and before the view is returned (not using `getView()` but the actual pointer for eg. `View v`).

At the end of my activity's `onCreate` method, I create a `FragmentTransaction` to display my fragment:

**Inside Activity:**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_club);
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.CreateClubHolder, newClubFormFragment.newInstance());
ft.commit();
```

Here is my fragment_no_club_membership.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.com/android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 ...
 ...
 <TextView
      android:name="@+id/noClub_oops"
```

I've tired cleaning the project and running again. Same null pointer exception.

Here is the stack trace (edited folder path name for privacy):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
  at com.myname.cs.createClub.NoClubMembershipFragment.onViewCreated(NoClubMembershipFragment.java:52)
```

**UPDATE:**

I neglected to include code where I also retrieved a button in the onViewCreated method:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mHelveticaTF = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Helvetica.otf");
    oopsTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noClub_oops); // I've tried getView() and getActivity() - same result
    oopsTV.setTypeface(mHelveticaTF); // Null pointer exception here.
    // oopsTV.isActivated() crashes the program.

    createClubButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.noClub_create);
    // createClubButton.isActivated() does NOT crash the program. Button is not null.
}
```

I have just found out that the button is not null and I'm able to retrieve it from `findViewById`. When I get rid of the calls to change the Typeface, I get no exceptions and I can see my fragment's views on my app, TextViews and all. It seems that the TextViews are inflating, but I'm not able to retrieve them. When I run `isActivated` on these TextViews, I get a null pointer exception.

So it seems that the issue is that I cannot retrieve TextViews, despite that they are properly inflating, but I can retrieve other components like Buttons.

Comment: what is name of xml you mentioned  above ?

Comment: fragment_no_club_membership.xml. I will edit to reflect this.

Comment: Please include the stacktrace

Comment: Check your .iml file first, if ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH is set to "/assets", make sure your font is inside /app/assets/fonts/ instead of /app/src/main/assets/fonts/

Comment: @anhtuannd Thanks. The issue seems to be that oopsTV is null.

Comment: So is it okay if retrieve textview in onCreateView?

Comment: No, sorry. The issue is unresolved. I'm still unable to retrieve TextView's in either onCreateView or onViewCreated but can retrieve Buttons. Could the assets folder path affect this? I'm not sure where the .iml file is located but I did not think this was the issue.

Comment: I think, android:name="@+id/noClub_oops", should be android:id. Is that a typing error?

Comment: @I_A_Mok That worked! I can't believe I missed that. Wasn't getting any compilation errors or warnings with `android:name` and Android Studio didn't give me a warning in the fragment file (and auto-complete was working as if it had the connection). If you want to answer formally I can accept your answer.

Comment: where your variable view is initialized? in onCreate view change this return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_no_club_membership, container, false); to  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_no_club_membership, container, false); return view: May this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use *Context* instead of *getActivity()*.
You can get *Context* from parent Activity as below in fragment.

```
private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext=context;
}
```

And also if you need Activity instance in Fragment than simply cast *Context* to *Activity* as below

```
Activity activity= (Activity) mContext;//If needed
```

More on for good code quality, you can this standards.